# how do you calculate the private exponent in asymmetric key encryption

Tags: rsa, public-key

Here is an excellent paper on the math of asymmetric key encryption: http://www.mathaware.org/mam/06/Kaliski.pdf‎

See the example on Page 6.

The public key = $55$
Primes used to calculate public key are $5$ and $11$.

$e = 3$

Now see the appendix:
$L = \mathrm{LCM}(p-1, q-1) = 20$

The paper states $de = 1 \mod L$

I can't figure out how he gets the value of $d = 7$

Comment: Except for the value of $e$, and the use of $\varphi(n)=(p-1)\cdot(q-1)$ rather than $\mathrm{LCM}(p-1, q-1)$, this question is a duplicate of [this one](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5889/555) which has a fair answer, and [others](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2292/555).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compute the modular inverse of $e \pmod {20}$ with the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures), but in this simple case with $e=3$ you can guess $d=7$ because $3\times 7 = 21$.

Comment: Is there any simple method to demonstrate the concept of public key/private key, i.e, just to illustrate the concept, not necessarily for security?

Comment: Can `d` be 47 instead of 7? `de % L = 47*3 % 20 = 121 % 20 = 1`